# How to prove the following result about expectation of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

I want to prove the following result: 
Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable defined on a probability space $\Omega$. Then

$$\sum_{\omega\in\Omega:\ X(\omega)\geq\frac{\mathbb{E}X}{2}}\mathbb{P}(\omega)X(\omega) \geq \frac{\mathbb{E}X}{2}$$

I need it in another proof, but I am not sure whether it is true at all. Can anyone help me with the proof? Thanks

Comment: What's $\mathbb{P}(\omega)$?

Comment: The accepted answer shows that this is true if you replace the central $>$ with $\ge$.  The strict inequality isn't true; e.g., if $X(\omega)=0$ everywhere, both sides are zero.

Answer (score 2):

Assume not, and call this assumption (*). Then:

$E[X] = \sum_{\omega : X(\omega ) < \frac{E[X]}{2}} P(\omega) X(\omega)  + \sum_{\omega : X(\omega ) \ge \frac{E[X]}{2}} P(\omega) X(\omega)$ 
$< \sum_{\omega : X(\omega ) < \frac{E[X]}{2}} P(\omega)  \frac{E[X]}{2} + \frac{E[X]}{2}$
$\le \frac{E[X]}{2} + \frac{E[X]}{2} = E[X]$. Contradiction.

Comment: ok, thanks, I understood